Paley graph simulator
I'm looking for a browser simulation or Python code to simulate Paley graphs.
When the user inputs $n$, the number of vertices, the graph, with all of its edges and vertices and labels or whatever, should be shown.
In addition, the code should print the number of cliques and the size of the maximum sized clique.
Preferably the vertices should be in some nonwhite color.
I am not very experienced in coding.
I would appreciate it if someone could give me code, or a place where someone has already done this.
I know someone has done it before because I see Paley graph images on Google Imagee, that are probably code generated, but I can't find simulation software.
Thank you!

Do you mean Paley graphs or Cayley graphs?

@reinierpost I mean Payley Graphs - Which connect vertices that differ by a quadratic residue

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_graph

@reinierpost Yes, that is the wikipedia. I am looking for a simulation or a code that generates them

I've taken the liberty to clean up the text.
